# How can I know the type of ground from given coordinates using Python

Tags: python, coordinates, soil

I would like to know what type of soil (ground) is a given coordinate (lat&lon). For instance, if a coordinate is rural soil, a road, a building, etc. Is it possible? I've tried:

```
import requests
url = "https://rest.isric.org/soilgrids/v2.0/properties/query?lon=34.5&lat=1.299"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

However, the output JSON is not clear the type of soil.

Comment: Soil is complicated. What sort of answer are you expecting? The URL is an interface to the soilgrids system: https://soilgrids.org/ which returns a lot more info than the soil type.

Comment: There's also a "/classification" URL that returns a most probable type and a list of the 5 most probable types. Did you want to us that instead? eg `https://rest.isric.org/soilgrids/v2.0/classification/query?lon=-72&lat=-9&number_classes=5` Note this is strictly soil, it can't tell you if its a building or a road.

Comment: If you want to know whether the ground has a road, building, a crop etc., what you are looking for is not soil type, but rather land use or land cover.

Comment: @Spacedman and each class which type belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for landcover classifications...

Some good global open-access datasets are:

- [Climate Cange Initiative (CCI) Landcover](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/)
- [ESA WorldCover](https://esa-worldcover.org/en)

Comment: Do you know how to download data info from ESA WorldCover? I mean the class of each coordinate in numerical

Comment: hey, check the "data-download" section here: https://esa-worldcover.org/en/data-access   there are descriptions on how to download the data both via the viewer or via a python interface (you need to register but it should be free)

Comment: you can also get the whole data (120GB) from zenodo (https://zenodo.org/record/5571936#.YXA3ehpBxPY)

Comment: I've downloaded the whole data, however, it is tif images. I'm looking for a class type coverland when checking a specific lat&lon (or small area). Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean here... the files are geo-coded tiffs that include projection information and with the help of python libraries such as `rasterio` (or `xarray` + `rioxarray`) you should be capable of extracting the data based on lon/lat...

Comment: I want to get the class value as defined in here (https://worldcover2020.esa.int/data/docs/WorldCover_PUM_V1.1.pdf) [page 13] from a tif image. The goal would be: 1- transform each pixel center (x,y) to lat&lon and 2) for each lat&lon know the above class.

Comment: well... the values in the GeoTIFF should represent the "Map code" (the first column of the table) so all you need to do is identify the point in the tif, get the value and check what that value means from the table

Comment: If you have troubles with that, check for similar issues or open a new one!

Comment: it is what I was doing until now!!!! in words it looks easy

Comment: ... since I'm in a helpful mood today... checkout the update! :-)

Comment: I removed the update here and added it as answer to your new issue